# Prototype/Scriptaculous/JavaScript Data Picker control

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

In a current project we need a calendar control that can display 2 months at a time rather than the standard 1 month. Unfortunately the project is heavily tied to the Prototype API and Scriptaculous, so the option of using jQuery or any other framework is unavailable. So the control needs to be written in Prototype, Scriptaculous or standard JavaScript.

Does anybody know of any such control?

Thanks,

Chris

NOTE: I forgot to mention it originally, but we are tied to the 1.5 version of Prototype.

Answer (score 2):

Would [this script](http://stephencelis.github.com/timeframe/#example_information) be good for your project ?

Comment: Thank you for the response, and yes that would be good for the project, however I forgot to mention originally but we need something that can run on v1.5 of Prototype or earlier - sorry for this, and I have amended the original post.

Comment: Argh :( This will make your research a lot harder, as all the libs I know only work on 1.6. If this script is OK for you, you'll need to hack it to make it work.